# Brouwer fixed poin in 1-D

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

In $\mathbb R_{+}$ (non-negative) I realize that any nonnegative valued continuous function $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ where $X, Y \subseteq \mathbb  R_{+}$ with a negative finite gradient has a fixed point.

But the Brouwer fixed point theorem tells us that the function should map the domain into codomain, i.e., $Y\subseteq X$. Is this required in the above case? 
I feel that even if the $Y \supset X$ the fixed point exists.

I mean if the function in the following figure didn't cut the red line and instead cut the $x$ axis say at 0.6 still the fixed point exists.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me-de-Brouwer-dim-1.svg
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem

Edit:
I forgot to mentions that:

The domain $X$ has left end $0$ and both $X, Y$ are closed. (like in the picture)

Thank you.

Comment: If $X=[1,2]$ and $Y=[5,6]$ how can $f:X\to Y$ have a fixed point? So your "realization" isn't quite accurate. It's unclear what you are trying to say there.

Comment: I think I missed a point. I included that in the Edit. My confussion is $Y \supset X$ and still have a fixed point under conditions mentioned in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\{1,2\}$ and let $f\colon X\to X$ be $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=1$. You probably want to assume $X$ and $Y$ are closed intervals.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot a point which I now included in the Edit. Could you please provide a counter example including that point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ X= (1,2)$, $Y=(0,3)$. Then  $f(x)=1-\frac x2$ has no fixed point.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot a point which I now included in the Edit. Could you please provide a counter example including that point.

Comment: Even with the edit, Hagen's example still works; you can take $X=  [0,1]$, $Y = [0,3]$, $f(x) = 3-x$.

Comment: Hello fuglede. In your example for the given $X=[0,1]$ $Y=[2,3]$. That is not what I asked. I mean when $Y \supset X$ there is a fixed point. But in your example $Y$ is not a super set of $X$.